# Android Menu Text Color Change

Tags: android

I am trying Material theme and changing the background and text color of Menu and items. Using the below style it works fine on the Toolbar, but the menu pop up while pressing device menu button shows no change in text color though the background got changed. Please help to change the text color as mentioned.
[image]

```
<resources>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/accent</item>

    <!-- Menu Items -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item>

    <!-- Menu Items -->
</style>



<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/accent</item>

</style>
<style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/accent</item>

</style>
<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If any of given answers solved your question, please accept it for future user reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**try this create this theme**

```
<style name="TextAppearance" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
   <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

**than apply this theme in your Activity theme like this**

```
<style name="your_theme" parent="your_parent">
  <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
```

**or try this**

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    int positionOfMenuItem = 0; 
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString("My red MenuItem");
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
    item.setTitle(s);
}
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, thanks for your suggestion, but can it be done without Sherlock ? I tried importing it into my existing project and resulted into many compilation errors

Comment: @BharatKumar chek updated ans try to set programatically

Comment: Hi Nilesh, your second suggestion works. Thanks. Even though i was looking for some solutions from styles/themes, but this solves my problem and so i am accepting your answer for now.

Comment: Perfect answer, it's Working

Comment: @NileshRathod you just saved my life wit the "or try this" option!!!
There is a bug in every SDK lower than the new API 29: for "android:secondaryTextColor", Android does not pull the color value from values-night folder if you implement dark mode.
I need that attribute to color Menu items which use "secondaryTextColor". 
I could set the color programmatically like this, gold !!

Comment: I used  `<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse</item>` for dark theme

Answer (score 12):

One simple line in your theme :)

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: Hi Prashanna, its already in my theme bt has no change on color..pls check the code i had updated along with question

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of the overflow menu background by adding a new style in style.xml.

```
<style name="OverflowMenu"
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyOverflowMenu</item>
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="MyOverflowMenu" 
parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
<item name="android:popupBackground">@color/your_color</item> 
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // note if you want to style popup menu in toolbar    
 step 1-- Add your theme in toolbar 

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MyPopupTheme" />

    step 2-- add style in styles.xml

    <style name="MyPopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/red </item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/yellow</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/yellow</item>
    </style>


// note if you want to style menu text color  in toolbar itself
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/Mytoolbartheme"/    /> 


    <style name="Mytoolbartheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/text_color</item>

    </style>

    // if you use android x then toolbar is
       <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white"

                app:popupTheme="@style/MyPopupTheme"
                android:background="@color/colorsplash"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add one simple line in your theme .I hope this will solve your problem.

```
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_color</item>
```

enjoy..